# How do I add additional horizontal spacing between two figures in latex?

Tags: spacing, subfloats, sharelatex

The two pictures are too similar to have right next to each other, therefore additional spacing is preferred. The code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_0.png}
       \caption{1}
       \label{fig:table2}
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_4.png}
       \caption{2}
       \label{fig:table2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Tabels}\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What package was this compiled with? I can’t get it to build.

Answer (score 51):

Use `\hspace{amount}` or `\hfill` if you want the right subfigure get shifted to the right margin between the two subfigures:

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_0.png}
       \caption{1}
       \label{fig:table2}
   \end{subfigure}\hfill% or \hspace{5mm} or \hspace{0.3\textwidth}
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_4.png}
       \caption{2}
       \label{fig:table2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Tabels}\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}
```

Note that `\hspace{x}` must be followed by a `%`char immediately to prevent extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the space, you can also use `\hspace*{\fill}`