# Using figure* moves image to a new page in a 2-column document. Is there a way to prevent it?

Tags: floats, subfloats, two-column

I am using `\begin{figure*}[H]` since I want my figure to span to the whole page width while on double column page but it is causing the figure to move to a new page (despite using `[H]` to place the floating image at a precise location. This doesn't happen when I am using `\begin{figure}[H]` but in that case, I am unable to prevent the image from overlapping with the text in the adjoining column. Is there a way to fix this issue?

PS: Here's the snippet of the code that I am using:

```
\begin{figure*}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{your-figure-file}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. Please try to add a minimal working example (MWE) which is a whole document starting from `\documentclass{` and ending in `\end{document}` So that we can run it on our end and help you?

Comment: Also, `figure*` would normally try to put the figure at the top of the page as it is hard for latex to calculate the boxes when in two columns. You could use `multicol` package. check out this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30988/90297

Comment: `figure*` does not have an `[H]` (or `[h]` option.  It can not be `here` as it has to span at the top of the page

Comment: For example of use `table*` or `figure*` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/704980 .

Comment: You can go from twocolumn to onecolumn and back using https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page/531802?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C40.8168#531802 but you still need to put the code in the previous page.

Comment: LaTeX can't back up.  If there is already something on the page in the first column, any two-column (starred) float will be forced to a new page.  Find a place in the input, between paragraphs, that is definitely still on the previous page, and move tte input for the `figure*` there.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of earlier questions that contain the answer, but they also contain so much other information that this answer is hard to find.

The key fact here is that (La)TeX can't backtrack.  So if there is already something on the page in the first column, any two-column (starred) float will be forced to a new page. Find a place in the input, between paragraphs, that is definitely still on the previous page, and move the input for the `figure*` there.